# Store file list of current directory to a file

Tags: command-line, bash, ls

How can I get a list of all files in the current directory and store that to a file named `mycurrent` using the command-line?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest method is to simple run the following command from the current directory:

```
ls > mycurrent
```

There are many options available to the `ls` command to tailor the output to your specific needs.

Comment: Perhaps this is just a matter of opinion but it might be worth mentioning that by renaming "mycurrent" to "mycurrent.txt" in the command you can make it not only clear that file in question is a text file but also make it less of a hassle to open the file if it is ever sent to a different OS.

Comment: Even less of a hassle will be if you translate newline to carriage return + newline. There's no requirement for that, however, and we're not sending anything to a different OS. It's only a "what if" case. Bigger issue at hand is potentially bad filenames, and parsing of `ls`, which should never be done.